# Questions about Sage

Tags: support, allowed-questions, asking-questions

I posted a question about Sage: [SageMath: Embed all roots of a polynomial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/571876/sagemath-embed-all-roots-of-a-polynomial)

Now I discovered that there's http://ask.sagemath.org Q&A site with the same format as SE (therefore having the same benefits). Should I repost my question there? And if so, should I delete my question here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First thing to note is that `ask.sagemath.org` is powered by AskBot, and is not part of the StackExchange network. Therefore we cannot in fact migrate your question there for you. In general I would prefer that the usual rules about "please don't cross post" apply more broadly on the internet; but that's just me.

Personally I would highly recommend asking the question in the most appropriate forum. That means that *if I were the one facing this problem*, I would delete my question on MSE (provided that it has not generated any useful comments or answers) and ask on the SageMath website instead. This is mostly out of consideration that *volunteer time is limited* and I would prefer not to have people's efforts duplicated across different websites.

On the other hand, if someone has already provided a useful answer or comment, I would leave the question up because I think silently deleting the question and hence hiding that person's contribution is rude.

Whether you delete or not is up to you. But if you don't, I hope you will provide cross links to the two versions of the questions, so that answers provided by folks on either website will be more easily found by visitors to the other website.